# List-view groups with Qt?

Tags: windows, qt, listview

We have ListView.Groups in .NET. Is there an equivalent in Qt (without using Windows APIs)?

I am unable to find anything that indicates support for this in the documentation for Qt.

Example in Windows Vista/7: http://i50.tinypic.com/zumgyg.jpg

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like that is very easy to do with [Qt model-view](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.6/model-view-programming.html) control.

It's a little confusing at first, but basically all lists, tree ctrls and grids are treated in the same way - which lets you do interestign combiantions of them very easily.

Edit: [Casey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/107609/casey) posted a useful comment in an answer that was deleted.
Here is the text and the link:

> creating your tree model is pretty
>   straight forward. To create that
>   "grouped" effect where the parent
>   nodes look different then their
>   children, I would suggest creating an
>   ItemDelegate then setting it on your
>   view using setItemDelegate[1](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.6/model-view-programming.html). In the
>   Delegate's paint function you can
>   detect whether the index is a header
>   or now, and draw something
>   appropriately. When you get there if
>   you need help, start another question
>   and I can post an example.

http://doc.trolltech.com/4.6/qabstractitemview.html#setItemDelegate

Comment: Thank you. I'll have a look at that. Anything else that can help is much appreciated.

Comment: There are examples included with Qt and some tutorials on the web - start here (http://doc.trolltech.com/4.0/qt4-interview.html) for an overview

Comment: Somehow Casey's comments disappeared. The most recent one had very valuable information and I was not able to see it before it disappeared. I can see most of it though under "Recent Activity". Casey said (in short), "To create that 'grouped' effect where the parent nodes look different then their children, I would suggest creating an ItemDelegate then setting it on your view using setItemDelegate. In the Delegate's paint function you can detect whether the index is a header or row, and draw something appropriately".
I think that's the best answer I got so far. Thank you, Casey!

Comment: @Sarah - when an owner deletes an answer, unfortunately any comments are also deleted. If you have 10K rep you can read them. I have added casey's comment to my answer.